# Нужны ли самоответы в виде небольших (и не только) проектов на github и ему подобных?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, ответы, реклама

На основном сайте был задан вопрос: [C# WinForms не мигающий progressBar с возможностью задать текст внутри](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/922986/c-winforms-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-progressbar-%D1%81-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8)

Как уже некоторые заметили в комментариях, данный вопрос смахивает на своего рода "продвижение" своего репозитория.

У меня возникло не совсем такое, но все же схожее ощущение: у человека появилась задача в проекте/работе/захотелось, человек написал относительно большой и сложный проект по меркам форматирования вопросов/ответов этого сайта проект и решил поделиться этим проектом на ruSO, пояснил какие-то мелкие особенности и, по сути, оставил ссылку на свой репозиторий.

Думаю, многие на этом ресурсе могут выложить свои репозитории, оформив их как вопросы подобным образом, но большинство из них решают конкретную серьезную задачу, а не "вопрос" в моем понимании, что как-то не вяжется с тематикой сайта. Из этого и вытекает закономерный вопрос:

Нужны ли данному сайту подобные вопросы-ответы?

Comment: Но с другой стороны он прав - при копировании кода придётся поддерживать 2 места - репозиторий и ответ. Впрочем, я где-то писал код, а потом указывал, где можно найти актуальную версию - своего рода компромиссный вариант.

Comment: @Qwertiy, я больший акцент хотел сделать именно на самоответ, по такой логике можно хоть любой репозиторий сюда выложить.

Comment: Там единственный файл с кодом - его вполне можно в ответ скопипастить.

Comment: Хороший код, конечно, не помешает. Только вангую, что значительная часть таких проектов будет (мягко говоря), не очень хорошего качества. Однако, на это всегда можно ответить своей нелицеприятной оценкой как вопроса, так и ответа.

Comment: По-моему это принципиально не отличается от других ответов вида «Используйте библиотеку %название%», почему бы и нет. Но в общем случае «большой и сложный проект» рискует попасть под «вопрос слишком общий»

Comment: Я считаю, что они должны быть, но должны сопровождаться подробным объяснением того, как это все работает, а не просто ссылкой на сторонний ресурс. Если проект в пару строк кода (как это у указанного вопроса), то разобрать сам код в вопросе труда не составит. По поводу поддержки, на SO она не нужна, на SO нужно понимание того, как это сделать самому. А кому нужен свежий проект - ссылка в виде дополнения к основному ответу. Но ответ чисто ссылкой, извините, но это как то не правильно...